# Symbolic Algebraic Simplifier

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplification

I'm trying to solve this equation for x (or y).  Is there some way to do it in Matlab?  The "simplify" function (even with "steps",100,"All", true) doesn't do it.

```
-k+Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+Sqrt[(x-ax)^2+y^2]+Sqrt[(x-bx)^2+(y-by)^2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic solution does not exist in the general case, because the problem amounts to solving an 8th degree algebraic equation.

Defining the points `M(x,y)`, `O(0,0)`, `A(ax,0)` and `B(bx,by)` in the plane, the equation can be written as `MO + MA + MB = k`. The solution set `M` is the locus of points with constant sum of distances to 3 fixed points. This is called a [3-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) which is a curve of algebraic degree `2^3 = 8` in the general case.

If `F` is the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) of triangle `OAB` and `f = FO + FA + FB`, then no solutions exist for `k < f`. More material and links related to 3-ellipses can be found on this [multiellipse](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/multiellipse/multiellipse.shtml) page.